# dynamic selector for onClick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make simple onClick event

```
$('._1').click(function(){
        window.open('abc.html?parameter=1');
    });
```

in above case , i have _1 as a class,
now there are multiple such elements, and 1 here also acts as parameter to window.open request

but there are multiple click events i want to bind

```
var arrayOfValues = [1,2,4,6,7,8];
for(var z=0;z<arrayOfValues.length;z++)
    $('._'+arrayOfValues[z]+'').click(function(){
        window.open('abc.html?parameter='+arrayOfValues[z]);
    });
```

but this is not working

Comment: Are those `_1`. `_2` etc item dynamic?

Comment: does the second bit of code run **before** the elements with class names, `_1` `_2` etc are in the DOM?

Comment: sorry , yes , they get created dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arrayOfValues = [1,2,4,6,7,8];

$.each(arrayOfValues, function(key, val) {

   for(var z=0;z<arrayOfValues.length;z++) {
     $( '._'+arrayOfValues[z] ).click(function(){
                             ^ -- dont need quote here
       window.open('abc.html?parameter='+arrayOfValues[z]);

     });
   }

   // jQuery loop
   $( '._' + val ).click(function(){

        window.open('abc.html?parameter='+arrayOfValues[z]);

    });

});
```

But if you elements are added to document after page load then you should try with delegate event handler `.on()`.

```
var arrayOfValues = [1,2,4,6,7,8];

$.each(arrayOfValues, function(key, val) {

    $('body').on('click', '._'+ arrayOfValues[z], function(){

        window.open('abc.html?parameter='+arrayOfValues[z]);

    });

});
```

Comment: let me try this , only change , i see is , removal of ' ,Oh yes, also i need the second snippet for dynamic elements ,

Comment: @thecodeparadox I would replace the loop with `$.each(arrayOfValues, function(i, el) { ... })` - just to do it the jQuery way :D